# If statement doesn't work in JavaScript - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sublimetext3

I'm pretty new to HTML, and I'm trying to make a simple login system. I'm using Sublime Text 3 and "If" statements in JavaScript don't work. When I type 'if' in script, it goes purple, not JavaScript blue. Am I bad or is Sublime not working at all?

Code:

```
<html>
<body>
Kullanıcı adı: <input type="text" id="kadi">
<br>
Şifre:<input type="text" id="sifre">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="fun()">Giriş Yap</button>
<p id="p"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun(){
        var gkadi = document.getElementById().value;
        var gsif = document.getElementById().value;
        var dkadi = "ali";
        var dsif = "aa123"
        if(gkadi==dkadi){
            if(gsif==dsif){
                document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Giriş başarılı!";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Şifre yanlış";
            }
        } else {
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Kullanıcı adı yanlış.";
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that how Sublime Text chooses to syntax highlight your code has no bearing on how the browser will interpret and run it; that is, whether it works or not is dependent on the code and not on the tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax coloring can be misleading. It's not your if statement that is having problems. It's that `getElementById()` expects one argument which should be the id of the element that you are trying to get. With that change, your code works fine.

```js
function fun() {
  var gkadi = document.getElementById("kadi").value;
  var gsif = document.getElementById("sifre").value;
  var dkadi = "ali";
  var dsif = "aa123"
  if (gkadi == dkadi) {
    if (gsif == dsif) {
      document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Giriş başarılı!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Şifre yanlış";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Kullanıcı adı yanlış.";
  }
}
```

```html
Kullanıcı adı: <input type="text" id="kadi">
<br> Şifre:
<input type="text" id="sifre">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="fun()">Giriş Yap</button>
<p id="p"></p>
```

Comment: I feel such a dumb right now, lol. I knew the right thing but i forget it,